# Plotting Areas from an Integer Valued Matrix in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, graph, area

Suppose I have some NxM array called `L` in which each entry contains one of four integers, let's say `0,1,2,3`. Each number is grouped within the array, i.e. The upper right side of `L` will be entirely `1`, and the lower left will be all `2` and the middle will be all `0`, etc.

Is there any way to draw an area graph using MATLAB such that the graph will have axes ranging from 0 to N on one axis and 0 to M on the other, where areas corresponding to a specific integer in the matrix will be filled in with different colors in the same location on the graph?

The result should look something like this: [Link to Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2prYW.png)

I've been looking for a solution to this problem, but I can't seem to find some sort of easy answer anywhere.

Let me know if I should clarify anything else.

Comment: Have you tried `imagesc`?

Comment: I did not know of such a function. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a simple [`imagesc`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html)?

```
L = [0 0 0 1 1 1
     0 0 1 1 1 1
     0 0 0 1 1 2
     0 0 1 1 2 2
     0 0 0 2 2 2
     3 3 3 3 2 2
     3 3 3 3 3 3]; %// example data
cmap = [1 .5 .5    %// light red
        .5 1 .5    %// light green
        .5 .5 1    %// light blue
        .5 .5 .5]  %// grey
imagesc(L);        %// show image
colormap(cmap)     %// use colormap
axis image         %// set same scale on both axes
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to choose the color of each area?

Comment: Sure, with [`colormap`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html). Please see edited answer